# How to print all Drupal commerce order variables available inside the template?

Tags: theming, commerce

I'm struggling to understand how to print out all order information at the order view link, including the order author.

I mean printing it out at  **/admin/commerce/orders/XXX/view**

I've manage to get the page--admin--commerce--orders.tpl.php working, but how do I find all the variables?

I've tried with dpm($account), and dpm($content), with no luck.

ie. How may I print out the author of the order?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dpm($order)` for this.  This will give you most of what you need including the order author's uid:

```
$order->uid
```